# Filter blob by tags using SAS-token in azure CLI fails with authentication error

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-cli

Using Azure CLI I am trying to find all the blobs using tag filters. But I am unable to do so. I get the error

“Authentication failure. This may be caused by either invalid account key, connection string or sas token value provided for your storage account.”

Below is the CLI command I tried

```
az storage blob filter --tag-filter  "@container= 'containerxx' and Tag1='value'" --account-name stracc1 --sas-token "sv=2021-08-06&st=2022-10-11T07%3A40%3A00Z&se=2022-10-13T07%3A40%3A47Z&sr=c&sp=racwdxltf&sig=mZ4%2F4oXQV3Y4xcBoxxxxxEjJ1zmozb3ikmEddRc%3D"
```

I tried to confirm if the sas token provided is valid by running below command and it does execute fine returning a json. This confirms that the SAS token is valid. You can also see I have given Filter tag permission (f) in sas token generated.

az storage blob exists --account-name stracc1 --container-name containerxx --name yy.html --sas-token "sv=2021-08-06&st=2022-10-11T07%3A40%3A00Z&se=2022-10-13T07%3A40%3A47Z&sr=c&sp=racwdxltf&sig=mZ4%2F4oXQV3Y4xcBoxxxxxEjJ1zmozb3ikmEddRc%3D"

Kindly help.

**Update/Additional info:**  I have generated SAS on the container level, not at storage account level and I want it to work with container level SAS. I did give a try adding '?' aswell into the SAS but getting same error

Comment: Github issue just for tracking https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/24171

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment i m getting the same error as below.***

[image]

To resolve this error, make sure you are provided correct storage account name and SaS token like below.

To generate SAS token in your ***storage account -> shared access signature -> allowed resource group -> generate SAS token*** like below. *In your sas token I observe starting `?` is missing.*

[image]

Check whether you have given correct tag=value in your blob container as below.

[image]

***When I run this below command got result successfully like below.***

```
az storage blob filter --tag-filter  "@container= '<Container name >' and tag='< file body index tag >'" --account-name <str account name> --sas-token "< SAS-Token >"
```

***Output***:
[image]

---

### **Update:**

As per discussion you are unable to use an generated SAS on a storage account level alternatively you can use this command as below

```
az storage blob filter --tag-filter  "@container= '<containername>' and tag='val' " --account-name <accountname> --auth-mode "key"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @imran Thanks for offering help. I see you have generated SAS on a storage account level. However I have generated SAS on the container level and I want it to work with container level SAS. I did give a try adding '?' aswell into the SAS but getting same error.. Wishing you can help with my desired kind of settings. Thanks.

Comment: if you generate container level sas token it's gives an error instead of that u can use  `--account-key`  "<access key>"   or SAS token on storage account level only.
![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/TlydVbW.png)

Comment: Thats not possible for my case in hand because sharing keys or account sas means i cant have granular access control which I badly need to keep it that way.

Comment: please check this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-filter

Comment: Does it mean I cant use container SAS on this command? I am not sure on this as nothing is explicitly told. I tried REST API way and that works with container SAS

Comment: According to MsDocs you can use azure storage sas token ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/NQD2mvn.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248803/discussion-between-imran-and-garuda).